# How to make spaces between flex elements stay still in the same position while changing size of the browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a project: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anami90/pen/pWgmeX?editors=1100)

When I change browser size the letters climb to each other.

I need to find the way to lock the spaces between them. The letters has to be done like it is, I mean polygon. What to do to implant the letters to the divs, and has always the same spaces between them?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
      .flexContainer {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      background: pink;
    }

    .letsPlay {
      display: flex;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 2px solid red;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #lFirstLine {
      position: relative;
      background: lightgreen;
      height: 50%;
      width: 25%;
    }

    #eFirstLine {
      position: relative;
      background: green;
      height: 50%;
      width: 25%;
    }

    #tFirstLine {
      position: relative;
      background: lightgreen;
      height: 50%;
      width: 25%;
    }

    #sFirstLine {
      position: relative;
      background: green;
      height: 50%;
      width: 25%;
    }

    #pSecondLine {
      position: relative;
      background: CornflowerBlue;
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    #lSecondLine {
      position: relative;
      background: blue;
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    #aSecondLine {
      position: relative;
      background: CornflowerBlue;
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    #ySecondLine {
      position: relative;
      background: blue;
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    #exclamationMarkSecondLine {
      position: relative;
      background: CornflowerBlue;
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    .lFirst {
      position: absolute;
      background: black;
    }

    .lFirst.square {
      right: 42px;
      bottom: 7px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .lFirst.parallelogram {
      right: 17px;
      bottom: 1px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      transform: skew(-45deg);
    }

    .lFirst.triangleSmall1 {
      right: 55px;
      bottom: 1px;
      height: 16.92px;
      width: 33.84px;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .lFirst.triangleSmall2 {
      right: -7px;
      bottom: -2px;
      height: 16.92px;
      width: 33.84px;
      transform: rotate(135deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .lFirst.triangleMiddle {
      right: 57px;
      bottom: 86px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 48px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .lFirst.triangleBig1 {
      right: 39px;
      bottom: 19px;
      height: 33.84px;
      width: 67.68px;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .lFirst.triangleBig2 {
      right: 38px;
      bottom: 54px;
      height: 33.84px;
      width: 67.68px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .e {
      position: absolute;
      background: black;
    }

    .e.square {
      right: 51px;
      bottom: 36px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .e.parallelogram {
      right: 32px;
      bottom: 75px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      transform: skew(-45deg);
    }

    .e.triangleSmall1 {
      right: 69px;
      bottom: 41px;
      height: 16.92px;
      width: 33.84px;
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .e.triangleSmall2 {
      right: 8px;
      bottom: -3px;
      height: 16.92px;
      width: 33.84px;
      transform: rotate(135deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .e.triangleMiddle {
      right: 20px;
      bottom: 0px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 48px;
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .e.triangleBig1 {
      right: 49px;
      bottom: -5px;
      height: 33.84px;
      width: 67.68px;
      transform: rotate(225deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }

    .e.triangleBig2 {
      right: 49px;
      bottom: 70px;
      height: 33.84px;
      width: 67.68px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class=letsPlay>

         <div id=lFirstLine>
            <div class="lFirst square"></div>
            <div class="lFirst parallelogram"></div>
            <div class="lFirst triangleSmall1"></div>
            <div class="lFirst triangleSmall2"></div>
            <div class="lFirst triangleMiddle"></div>
            <div class="lFirst triangleBig1"></div>
            <div class="lFirst triangleBig2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id=eFirstLine>
           <div class="e square"></div>
          <div class="e parallelogram"></div>
          <div class="e triangleSmall1"></div>
          <div class="e triangleSmall2"></div>
          <div class="e triangleMiddle"></div>
          <div class="e triangleBig1"></div>
          <div class="e triangleBig2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id=tFirstLine></div>
        <div id=sFirstLine></div>

        <div id=pSecondLine></div>
        <div id=lSecondLine></div>
        <div id=aSecondLine></div>
        <div id=ySecondLine></div>
        <div id=exclamationMarkSecondLine></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because the width on `.letsPlay` is a percentage, the boxes containing the letters will continue to shrink with the browser, and the letters will eventually push together.**

To fix this, try a width of `500px` or something similar on your `.letsPlay` element. Unfortunately, you'll need another solution if you want all your letters to fit in on devices thinner than 500px.

Comment: Thank You very much! I did like You said. I was wondering it is some option to style every small black element with % not like now, and then make it stay still in the same position of the container styled also with % and not make it broken when the browser sizes changes, but it is not possible, right?

Comment: If you used all percentages rather than a fixed number of pixels, you may be able to get it to shrink appropriately. But if possible, images would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can hard code a width in, instead of with a %. Change it from `width-right: 500%` to `width-right: 500px` - or whatever you want it to be